# how to pass a new date value to URL by button in flask using python code only (not js)

Tags: python, html, flask, url

I am working on application in flask which displays rota schedules for employees for informative purpose. I managed to display current month of rota for a chosen employee. It looks like that:

[Picking employee's name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU9tB.png)

[table with rota for the name picked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcMwN.png)

It shows current month as I enter the interval value as a current date.

the URL for it is: http://127.0.0.1:5000/individual/printrota/2020-09-14?pickname=Deniz

When I change the date directly in the URL for i.e. 2020-10-14 it will show correctly the October's 2020 rota schedule for the chosen driver. I would like to program a button "next month" and "previous month" to let people change the dates using buttons. I wrote a function which does it but I don't know how to pass the values to build a correct URL.

This is my code in flask_app:

```
@app.route("/individual", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def individual():
    rotamonth = date.today()
    return render_template('individual.html', title='Individual', drivers=drivers, rotamonth=rotamonth)


@app.route("/individual/printrota/<rotamonth>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def printrota(rotamonth):
    pickname = request.args.get("pickname")
    dispmonth = datetime.today().strftime('%B %Y')
    for driver in drivers:
        if driver.first == pickname:
            chosen_driver = driver
            forward = chosen_driver.add_one_month()


            return render_template('printrota.html', chosen_driver=chosen_driver,mon_thu_times=mon_thu_times,fri_times=fri_times, sat_times=sat_times, sun_times=sun_times, dispmonth=dispmonth, rotamonth=rotamonth, forward=forward)

@app.route("/backmonth")
def backmonth():
    pass


@app.route("/individual/printrota/<rotamonth>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forward(rotamonth):

    return render_template('printrota.html')
```

And this is my templates code:

individual.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <div class="subpage">
    <h1>INDIVIDUAL ROTA</h1>
     <form action={{url_for('printrota',rotamonth=rotamonth)}}>
         <label>Choose a name:</label>
         <select name="pickname" id="pickname">
         {%for driver in drivers%}
           <option value={{driver.first}}>{{driver.first}}</option>
         {%endfor%}
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value="Pick a name">
     </form>
 </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

printrota.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="subpage">
<h1>{{chosen_driver.first}}'s rota for {{dispmonth}}</h1>
    <form>
    <button class="move_rota" type="submit">Previous month</button>
    </form>
    <form action={{url_for('printrota', rotamonth=forward, chosen_driver=chosen_driver)}}>
    <button class="move_rota" type="submit">Next month</button>
    </form>
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>DAY</th>
        <th>DUTY</th>
        <th>TIME SPAN</th>
    </tr>
{%for item in chosen_driver.clnd(rotamonth, period='M')%}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.start_time.date()}}</td>
        <td>{{item.start_time.strftime('%A')}}</td>
        <td>{{item.label}}</td>
        {% if item.start_time.weekday() in range(0,4)%}
            <td>{{ mon_thu_times[(chosen_driver.clnd(item.start_time.date()).label)] }}</td>
            {% elif item.start_time.weekday() == 4%}
            <td>{{ fri_times[(chosen_driver.clnd(item.start_time.date()).label)] }}</td>
            {% elif item.start_time.weekday() == 5 %}
            <td>{{ sat_times[(chosen_driver.clnd(item.start_time.date()).label)] }}</td>
            {% elif item.start_time.weekday() == 6 %}
            <td>{{ sun_times[(chosen_driver.clnd(item.start_time.date()).label)] }}</td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I try to program the "next month" button first and then apply it to the other button respectively. When I press the button the URL looks like that:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/individual/printrota/2020-10-14?

and returns error:

TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

which means the date is passed correctly but the other argument (which is the picked employee) is not going up there and it cannot build the page as it is missing the argument 'pickname' which is needed to display correct schedule. I have no idea how to pass it to this URL?

I tried to look for help in the documentation and in similar questions here but nothing seems to be working for me here. Help!!